# jquery mobile 1.3.0 js adds ui class to my elements

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, stylesheet

I am facing problem, that when I include jquery mobile 1.3.0.js file, it automatically addw classes: ui-mobile-viewport and ui-overlay-c to html body tag in my websites, so the website have styles of jquery mobile stylesheet, so my styles are override by jquery styles.

I don't know what to do, I studied forum on their site and I did not find such a problem there.
Can anyone please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I want my style to be used, not the jquery styles without assigning id's and classes to every element and without making my css longer just to override the jquery's css

Comment: You can solve the problem by making your selectors more specific than their selectors, or by adding `!important` to your rules.

Comment: This is what I do not want to do, because it will make my css awfully long, isn't there any other solution.

Comment: Build your own JQM http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

Comment: What part of jQuerey Mobile do you want to use? And do you want to completely prevent jQM styling?

Answer (score 3):

As omar mentioned above you can build your custom css to avoid being ovride by JQM styles.

Else,
overide the `ui-mobile-viewport` and `ui-overlay-c` styles manually in  your style sheet and import it after the jqm style sheet. Also you can use `!import` to enforce your style.